# Display Unicode character in Wordpress sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, sidebar

I have created a custom sidebar with some Unicode characters but I have problem when viewing my Unicode characters. This is my sidebar code:

```
<?php
/**
* The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
*
* @package Theme Meme
*/
?>
<div class="col-md-4 site-sidebar" role="complementary">
<?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'post_group_sidebar' ) ) : ?>
    <h3 class="widget-title">Title in Unicodé</h3> </br>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to make it work, perhaps I have to add a meta tag to display the Unicode somewhere?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I am thinking whether the Sidebar is showing any content from a Database? You can always change your Database Coaltion to **utf8_general_ci**

Here is how to do it

1) Open and edit your **wp-config.php** file in the root of your Wordpress Website and replace the default **DB_CHARSET** and **DB_COLLATE** lines with this instead:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci' );
```

Save it back and see if that works.

Else you can also include one of the lines below in your PHP or HTML code.

In your code for PHP include this on top of your PHP Code:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

In HTML add the line below in between the `<head></head>` Tags or somewhere above the  tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help Miguel.
I will generate some data from db later but at the moment I am putting some html inside my sidebar. I have tried your suggestion by placing it just below the first line but it still does not help. Here is [my page](http://thoisuthoicuoi.com/?page_id=382/?pagename=post-cat&post_cat_name=0041) the sidebar title does not display Unicode for me. Thanks for any other suggestion.

Comment: How can you tell? Yes that's correct, I am using that class. Does it mean I have to modify the style to cater for Unicode? Sorry I am that good at working with css yet. I tried to modify the item in the list to include Unicode character but still does not display correctly. I also add the second line in my custom template but it does not help.

Comment: Edited Comment: You are welcome. I saw your Webpage I can see that the Widget title uses the "widget-title" class in your style.css. Also you are using the latest version of the Flato Theme. You can play arround with the font-family of your widget or the sidebar in style.css of your Template. I will reply if I get a better idea! 
Please also check the tutorial here to fix some of the Character Encoding Isues. https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-character-encoding-problem-in-wordpress-1480

Comment: Please check my main Tutorial Above again. I have Included how you can change the coalition of your Database to utf8_general_ci.

Comment: I have tried that. My was blank before for the DB_COLLATE but still does not work. I think this does not relate to the DB since my whole site is in Unicode and it displays ok. Maybe only within this sidebar?

Comment: Did you fix this issue?